# How can I transform the xtext DSL elements into XML?

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, transformation, xtext

I have created a grammar using xtext, and generated the DSL. Now, I want to transform the DSL elements (program that is conforming to the grammar) to XML elements. So, I am wondering if there is a framework that allows to do that using Java for example. I could open the files having the extension of the DSL using the eclipse editor "Sample Reflective Ecore Model Editor" and could visualize the elements of the DSL.
[image: DdTe4.png]

Comment: do you mean a specific xml or the xmi representation? using the sample reflective ecore model editor should work ootb (if you dont use xbase)

Comment: If I get the xmi representation, it would be very helpful, because I will be able to use Acceleo for example to do the transformation to xml.

Comment: so you are interested in a different xml than the xmi.
you should also be able to use accele directly with xtext

Comment: Yes, I want to transform the xmi data to an XML data that is conforming the capella modelling tool in order to visualize the transformed elements in a cappella graphical diagram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I was looking for. I am using Xtend with Xtext. A ".xtend" file is generated once the grammar is compiled. This file contains a method called doGenerate. It is here where I am transforming my code which is conforming to its xtext grammar to a Capella XML and inject it directly in the "melodymodeller" Capella project file.

Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean a transformation to the Capella Model? Then I would suggest not the XML, but bundle the Capella EMF model with your Xtext RCP and do a model-to-model transformation based on EMF (I would suggest Xtend, but QVT, Acceleo etc. can be used, too)